# Количество отображаемых элементов recyclerview при скроллинге

Tags: android, recyclerview

Имею 100+ items в recyclerview

Как сделать чтобы отображалось на экране только нужное количество, к примеру строго 5, скролл - следующие 5 и так до конца

Comment: Нетривиальная задача. Если хотите всё правильно сделать, смотрите в сторону [SnapHelper](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/SnapHelper.html)

Comment: Вы хотите чтобы каждый итем занимал 1/5 высоты списка или вам нужна подгрузка списка? Подгрузка автоматическая или по кнопке в конце списка?

Comment: Мне нужна автоматическая подгрузка..